# Thread stops when associated, but not owning, winform is hidden

Tags: multithreading, winforms, events

I'm hoping someone may be able to help diagnose some excruciating thread pain I seem experiencing.

My main form creates an instance of my FccEventListener class, which in turn creates a background thread that listens to a network port.  The main form then creates an instance of another form named frmPendingTransactions and passes fccEventListener into it's constructor.  frmPendingTransactions then subscribes to a number of events provided by the fccEventListener as well as another service named recyclerClient.

Everything seems to work fine.  I can Show and Hide (not Close) frmPendingTransactions as much as I like and fccEventListener continues to do it's thing no worries.  However, if a recyclerClient event fires that results in a call to the Hide() method, frmPendingTransactions is hidden, but the listening thread stops doing it's job.  If I Invoke the Hide() method, the thread stops doing it's job.  But if I skip the call to the Hide() method altogether and hide to form manually, which just uses the same code anyway, it's fine.

I tried converting to a BackgroundWorker and saw the same behaviour.

I don't understand how hiding form B (via an event triggered by another service) can possibly impact a thread that is owned by it's parent form, form A.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: FccEventListener starts a background thread and fires events which are being caught on a UI thread. My guess is that recyclerClient event is firing on a background thread, and is attempted to be handled on the foreground thread causing a cross thread error which is being caught somewhere in FccEventListener. But as you've supplied no code in your question it's impossible to diagnose.

Comment: I have a bunch of logging and exception handling that hasn't exposed the exception as yet.  There's a lot going on in there, but I'll try to distil the code down to something I can post.  It'll have to wait until the morning though.  FYI recyclerClient is a wdsl web service reference.